# Extracting the lines from a file which shows date more than 30 days

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

Experts,

I am new to scripting world

I am trying to keep the lines which are older than 30 days.
the file contains following lines

```
Server1 last patched on Mon Oct 11 09:50:47 2021
Server2 last patched on Fri Jun 3 07:53:36 2022
Server3 last patched on Fri Jun 3 11:58:26 2022
Server4 last patched on Fri Jun 17 12:58:59 2022
Server5 last patched on Fri Marc 17 04:12:51 2022
Server6 last patched on Mon Oct 17 23:08:24 2022
```

Thank you for your help.

expecting to keep the lines which are older than 30 days.
i have tried this

```
awk -v dat="Sun Oct 04 00:00:00 2022" -F':' '$5<dat' list.txt
```

gives same result

```
    Server1 last patched on Mon Oct 11 09:50:47 2021
    Server2 last patched on Fri Jun 3 07:53:36 2022
    Server3 last patched on Fri Jun 3 11:58:26 2022
    Server4 last patched on Fri Jun 17 12:58:59 2022
    Server5 last patched on Fri Marc 17 04:12:51 2022
    Server6 last patched on Mon Oct 17 23:08:24 2022
```

expected results is

```
Server1 last patched on Mon Oct 11 09:50:47 2021
Server2 last patched on Fri Jun 3 07:53:36 2022
Server3 last patched on Fri Jun 3 11:58:26 2022
Server4 last patched on Fri Jun 17 12:58:59 2022
Server5 last patched on Fri Marc 17 04:12:51 2022
```

the file entry is

```
server1 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo) - last patched on Tue Sep 20 10:45:56 2022
```

Comment: @markp-fuso
updated with expected results

Comment: @ 
glenn jackman
you are right, thanks for correcting it should be in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty is having to parse the timestamps into an actual time value: you can't just compare them as strings and expect chronological order.

Here's a bit of perl:

```bash
perl -MTime::Piece -lane '
    BEGIN {$start = (localtime) - 86400 * 30}
    $t = Time::Piece->strptime("@F[4..8]", "%a %b %d %T %Y");
    print if $t < $start;
' file
```

```
Server1 last patched on Mon Oct 11 09:50:47 2021
Server2 last patched on Fri Jun 3 07:53:36 2022
Server3 last patched on Fri Jun 3 11:58:26 2022
Server4 last patched on Fri Jun 17 12:58:59 2022
Server5 last patched on Fri Mar 17 04:12:51 2022
```

Note, I had to edit `Marc` to `Mar` to satisfy strptime's `%b` month abbreviation.

---

> if its in this format. 'server1 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo) - last patched on Tue Sep 20 10:45:56 2022'. do i need to change @F[14..18]

Yes. If the number of words before the date is variable, I'd use regex matching. I'm going to assume "last patched on" is always present:

```bash
perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
    BEGIN {$start = (localtime) - 86400 * 30}
    if (/last patched on (.+)/) {
        $t = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%a %b %d %T %Y");
        print if $t < $start;
    }
' file
```

---

I can't reproduce your error:

```bash
$ cat file
server1 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo) - last patched on Tue Sep 20 10:45:56 2022
Server1 last patched on Mon Oct 11 09:50:47 2021
Server2 last patched on Fri Jun 3 07:53:36 2022
Server3 last patched on Fri Jun 3 11:58:26 2022
Server4 last patched on Fri Jun 17 12:58:59 2022
Server5 last patched on Fri Mar 17 04:12:51 2022
Server6 last patched on Mon Oct 17 23:08:24 2022

$ perl -MTime::Piece -lne '
      BEGIN {$start = (localtime) - 86400 * 30}
      if (/last patched on (.+)/) {
          $t = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%a %b %d %T %Y");
          print if $t < $start;
      }
  ' file
server1 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo) - last patched on Tue Sep 20 10:45:56 2022
Server1 last patched on Mon Oct 11 09:50:47 2021
Server2 last patched on Fri Jun 3 07:53:36 2022
Server3 last patched on Fri Jun 3 11:58:26 2022
Server4 last patched on Fri Jun 17 12:58:59 2022
Server5 last patched on Fri Mar 17 04:12:51 2022
```

Comment: if its in this format. 'server1 - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo) - last patched on  Tue Sep 20 10:45:56 2022'.  do i need to change @F[14..18]

Comment: tried it, i got this error without any output 'Error parsing time at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Time/Piece.pm line 597, <> line 1."

Comment: That is "Marc". You need to fix that to "Mar" as an abbreviation for March

Comment: I have removed Marc has been fixed , it was a typo earliet.However i am getting same parsing error

Comment: What is line 1 in your data file?

Comment: Server1 - CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) - last patched on  Fri Oct 21 01:29:31 2022

Comment: Which of my one-liners are you running? Better use the second.

Comment: i am using the second one

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Add more of your input file to your question.